# Guy Debord - society of spectacle - thesis 3

Tags: marxism, situational-ethics

I'm reading the book by Guy Debord, ["society of spectacle"](https://www.marxists.org/reference/archive/debord/society.htm). I think it's quite known, but it's difficult to read!

In thesis number 3, he talks about a so called process of "unification". Can someone explain or illustrate what that could be? Is it like the opposite of alienation? Even formulated that way, I have a hard time figuring out what he means by that.

From what I understand about alienation, it's a part of human nature that is separated from humans (and appropriated by another individual or social class, like the conception of an object and the satisfaction of designing, producing it). If I understand it correctly, "unification" would be the (false feeling of) re-appropriation of that expropriated part of life, and in that case, through the contemplation of the Spectacle ... am I right?

I would like the opinion, the point of view of someone who is more familiar with Marxist philosophy.

Here is the thesis:

> "The spectacle presents itself simultaneously as all of society, as part of society, and as instrument of unification. As a part of society it is specifically the sector which concentrates all gazing and all consciousness. Due to the very fact that this sector is separate, it is the common ground of the deceived gaze and of false consciousness, and the unification it achieves is nothing but an official language of generalized separation."

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is definitively good enough as a working hypothesis. The relation between alienation and unification is one of the major topics of the book, i.e. something not defined but explored. The *Socienty of the Spectacle* is much easier to read as a whole than as a system, i.e. repeatedly rather than incrementally. Still, let me provide some background and some explanation:

**Alienation**

For Hegel, alienation basically is the result of reflection: the subject presents itself as an object when we reflect on it; the same goes for all our parts and all we are part of, our properties, the categories we think in, society, nature. For Hegel the unity is generated by the spirit or (at least in Marxist understanding) by thinking: ultimately the spirit realises that all the things that seem to be *other* objects are really its own product. Now, Marx’ critique is this: Marx claims Hegel has got it the wrong way, that Hegel’s philosophy has to be put on its feet. To understand this, recall Hegel’s Philosophy of Right: Hegel starts with the notion of property, this notion then leads to contradictions which require the new notions of contract, law, moral, family, society, and, finally, the proper »State« in which all the contradictions find their solution. One part of Marx’ critique is that Hegel only presents the *ideal* of unification but not the real praxis (the economy) which actually unifies. Perhaps more importantly, he tries to inverse the process: What if, Marx asks, the totality is not the reconciliation of contradictions but rather the process by which the contradictions (property, or, for the later Marx: commodities) are generated in the first place? This question is the basis for Marx’ project. But this reversal has important consequences for the notion of alienation: alienation no longer means that we have not (yet) understood that we and the object we are regarding are really the same; rather, our totality produces real contradictions, it produces conditions in which our parts and what we are part of, our products and what we are produced by, are not »ours«.

**Unification**

While in Hegel, alienation and unification can be seen as opposites (the alienation ultimatly disappears only in the final unification), even for Marx this is not true: the capitalist mode of production unifies (almost) everything, but alienation remains: the products of the worker are not her own, but present themselves as an alien and potentially hostile power. In Marx, however, the unification is not total, because the remaning alienation (although the later Marx no longer uses that notion) is understood to be visible and the necesessity obvious to abolish dispose of the mode of production that creates said alienation. This is where some 20th century Marxists disagreed: It seemed that the unification indeed tended to become total, and the question became how to explain that.

Debord provided one of these attempts.

**Society of the Spectacle**

›Alienation‹ occurs for the first time in Thesis 8: this is pretty Hegelian, »reciprocal alienation« means that »reality« as well as »spectacle« become what they are not, reality because it presents itself in the spectacle (therefore as something else than reality), while the spectacle is real, e.g. a spectacular concept of reality. While for Hegel and Marx alienation was between subject and object, Debord describes alienation in a process that is already removed from the subject. According to Marx, the subject creates her own alienation by producing; not so with Debord: the alienation has already happend before the subject even appears.

In Hegel, contemplation of the object is the process by which alienation is ultimately overcome, For Marx, contemplation (or thinking) provides us with what is required to change the conditions that create alienation. But for Debord, contemplation is exactly that what creates alienation: when we contemplate (watch, observe) we do not really critically analyse. Rather we understand reality in categories provided for us, in categories we use but did not create.

For Debord these categories (the spectacle) structure and constitute what is real to *us*. They create our reality. And they combine every aspect of reality. Everything *fits*. That is unification. At the same time, the spectacle (the cultural discourse, the political discourse, the way we see our surroundings in our roles as workers, commuters, tourists, revellers, etc.) is somewhat removed from what we really do (as opposed to our role).

Unification means that everything fits together, everything can be explained by something else and, therefore, everything that is can be justified. If alienation can be justified, any hope is lost. Debord’s project hinges on the hinges on the possibility that the unification is a wrong one.

So while Debord tries to explain why alienation and unification must present themselves in our society as identical, his project requires that we still can distinguish between them. And, indeed, there has been much discussion, if and how this is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer, yet there are still a few points that i don't understand : 
I quickly glanced Hegel's Philosophy of Right trying to find the answers myself but i am not sure what are the contradicitons that arise from property, then contract, law, morality, etc.

Comment: I'll write what i understood, please correct me then :
At first there is free, unlimited and "selfish" Will.
I understood property as the subject putting its free and unlimited will into an object. Yet Different wills may collide in putting themselves into the same object. So by paragraph 72, the contract is here to solve that and making it so they remain free (??). I understand that contracting with some other will is aknowledging that other and relinquishing property to that contract, which becomes kind of another will. So you own something by actually relinquishing it to another will

Comment: the contradiction being : "i am the owner of a thing as long as i cease to own it by "giving" it to another will, the contract, and aknowledging the other" (not aknowledging any other will, is it a base hypothesis ?). 

Law being here to ensure contracts don't collide, or that each party fulfills its commitment if the will of the contract and the will of a party were to diverge.

I am not sure how we go from law to right and morality, let alone  family, society, and the proper "State". Can you help me figure out what are the contradictions every time and how they are solved.

Comment: What is the "remaining alienation" ?

Answer (score 1):

The last sentence of the paragraph indicates that he does not consider alienation and unification opposites.

A spectacle creates a shared reference in our social history, and reaffirms tribal identities in the reactions that different tribes channel their membership into.  So it seems to create unity.

But he points out that this is only a parallelization of our alienations, not a reduction of them.  We are not really a part of the spectacle, we are its audience, so the sharing it mediates is not real joining.

Fighting alongside someone in a war may reverse alienation, watching one alongside them from a position of safety does not.